# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: confirmed_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i am creating a demo app with devise Authentication in rails

i am facing this error

```
rake aborted!
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: confirmed_at
```

my User.rb class is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

validates_presence_of :name
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false
end
```

and my db.seed.rb file code is

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)

puts 'SETTING UP DEFAULT USER LOGIN'
user = User.create! :name => 'First User', :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'please', :password_confirmation => 'please', :confirmed_at => DateTime.now
user2 = User.create! :name => 'Second User', :email => 'user2@example.com', :password => 'please', :password_confirmation => 'please', :confirmed_at => DateTime.now
puts 'New user created: ' << user.name
```

user.rb is a model class.
when i run command
$ bundle exec rake db:seed

i am facing this error 
  rake aborted!
    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: confirmed_at

Comment: please help me how to remove this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have to set `confirmed_at` while creating users, instead, you can call `confirm!` on each user object and you're done, and that's better 'cause calling `confirm!` does bunch of other things beside setting `confirmed_at`.

```
user = User.create! :name => 'First User', :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'please', :password_confirmation => 'please'
user.confirm!
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
Model.create!(fieldsValues, :without_protection => true)
```

In your case:

```
User.create!({:name => 'First User', :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'please', :password_confirmation => 'please', :confirmed_at => DateTime.now}, :without_protection => true)
```

`without_protection` wil allow you to set the values of protected fields

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the above two answers or disable protection in the application.rb to set white list attributes false like:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

And, you can add confirmed_at as attr_accessible but you don't need to set confirm_at to create new user as Ahmad Sherif mentioned.